# Reading text file from a certain string onwards in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
[11/01/15 - 17:50] REFA,2,5,600, 
[11/01/15 - 17:52] REFB,1,3,
[11/01/15 - 17:54] REFA,2,10,1200, 
[11/01/15 - 17:55] REFB,1,6,
```

I have a text file of several lines of the above format. How can I start reading the text file from REFA and store only 2,5,600 in matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very easily do that with regular expressions.  Simply find all parts of the string that begin with `[` and end with `]` and replace them with the null string, or `''`.  That can be done with [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html).

As such, read in the entire text file first, then eliminate the portions you don't need.  Assuming your text file is in a file called `text.txt`, do something like this:

```
fid = fopen('text.txt', 'r');
out = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
out = regexprep(out{1}, '\s*\[.*\]\s*', '');
```

The first line of code opens up your file for reading.  The next part reads in each line of your text into a cell array, where the output is a 1 element nested cell array, but each cell within this is a single line of your text file.  The last line accesses this single nested element and finds that portion of the string where there is white space, it beings with a `[` character, has a bunch of characters inside, then ends with `]` character and again some white space after that.  We find those portions of text, and replace them with the null string.  This effectively gives you only the portion of text you are looking for.

By placing your example text in a file called `text.txt`, this is what I get:

```
out = 

'REFA,2,5,600,'
'REFB,1,3,'
'REFA,2,10,1200,'
'REFB,1,6,'
```

Now if you just want to get the just the numerical values, you can just use indexing:

```
out = cellfun(@(x) x(6:end-1), out, 'uni', 0);
```

Now, to get this to work with your code (in your comments), try this:

```
fileID = fopen('stack.txt'); 
D = textscan(fileID, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n'); 
fclose(fileID); 
D = regexprep(D{1}, '\s*\[.*\]\s*', '');
D = cellfun(@(x) x(6:end-1), D, 'uni', 0);

%// Extract out the numbers now
numbers = regexp(D, '(\d+)*', 'tokens');

%// Only look at lines that have three numbers
idx = cellfun(@numel, numbers) == 3;

%// Extract out just those lines
numbers_extract = numbers(idx);

%// Convert from string to numbers
REFA.pkttype = cellfun(@(x) x(1), numbers_extract);
REFA.datalength = cellfun(@(x) x(2), numbers_extract);
REFA.ticks = cellfun(@(x) x(3), numbers_extract);
```

Comment: @Yaant3y - I added in more code to just get the numbers.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng, your solution does get rid of [ ]. But what I was trying to accomplish was to get the output produced by this code.

`fileID = fopen('stack.txt');
D = textscan(fileID,'%s %u8 %u8 %u16','Delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);

REFA.pkttype=D{2}(strcmp(D{1},'REFA'));
REFA.datalength=D{3}(strcmp(D{1},'REFA'));
REFA.ticks=D{4}(strcmp(D{1},'REFA'));`

This code only worked as it should when I edited the file manually as 
REFA,2,5,600, 
REFB,1,3,
REFA,2,10,1200, 
REFB,1,6,
before seeing getting your help. So how can I combine your code with this to get the same output?

Comment: yup it works. I would like to remove ' ' from the data so I can plot it nicely. I will work on it and get back if I can't. Thanks

Comment: @Yaant3y - Take your time.  I'll be here.  Good luck!

Comment: I manage to remove the ' in for example '2'. But what I am doing is run this code `fid = fopen('Stack_Junk.txt', 'r'); out = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n'); out = regexprep(out{1}, '\s*\[.*\]\s*', ''); outfid = fopen('OutputFile.txt', 'wt'); if outfid < 0 error('file creation failed'); end fwrite(outfid, evalc('disp(out)')); fclose(outfid);` and then manually search and replace in new file.

Comment: After that read the new file `fileID = fopen('OutputFile.txt'); D = textscan(fileID,'%s %u8 %u8 %u16','Delimiter',','); fclose(fileID); REFA.pkttype=D{2}(strcmp(D{1},'REFA')); REFA.datalength=D{3}(strcmp(D{1},'REFA')); REFA.ticks=D{4}(strcmp(D{1},'REFA'));` any elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by finding commas. Save the contents from the first comma to the last comma. The following code should work.  However, I am not sure for very large files.

```
readfin = fopen('myfile.txt','r');
lineno = 1;
% Read every line one by one
while(~feof(readfin))
   newline = fgets(readfin);
   index = find(newline == ',',1,'first');  % find first comma
   outdata = newline(index+1 : end-1);      % ignore first and last comma
   disp(outdata);                           % do whatever you need with your desired outdata here
end
```